# In netbeans, by default arrays are sort by value, how should I change it to by index

Tags: arrays, netbeans, netbeans-8

In Netbeans, 
While we creating a new array, and when we lookup into the variable > and expand array > It's show in order of sorting by value 
It was before sorting by index.

```
int[] nums = {2,0,2,1,1,0};
```

Attached a picture below for more clarity[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02KTN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click on the table header of the column you want to order by (in your case: click on "Name").